# Finding inverse of a function.

Tags: calculus

Could someone please help me finding the inverse of the following function: $$f(x)=
\frac{x-1}{\ln(x)}$$ where $x>0$?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is no solution in [elementary functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) but the inverse function is given by
$$ x = -y \mathcal{W}\left( -\frac{e^{-1/y}}{y} \right) $$

where $\mathcal{W}$ is the [product log function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

---

step by step solution:

$$ y= \frac{x-1}{\ln{x}} \Longrightarrow -\ln{x} = - \frac{x-1}{y} \Longrightarrow \exp{\left(-\frac{x}{y}\right)} = \exp{\left(-\frac{1}{y}-\ln{x} \right)}$$

Now multiply both sides with $\frac{x}{y}$ and get:

$$\frac{x}{y}\exp{\left(-\frac{x}{y}\right)} = \frac{\exp{\left(-1/y\right)}}{y}\Longleftrightarrow -\frac{x}{y}\exp{\left(-\frac{x}{y}\right)} = -\frac{\exp{\left(-1/y\right)}}{y}$$

Now apply the definition of $\mathcal{W}$ and my answer mentioned before follows.

Comment: yes, I know this, but I want to know how do you obtain this function?

Comment: @nicole please see answer below,both answer will help you

Comment: @user127001, I know this result, but can you please show me how do you obtain the product log function here?

Comment: I have made an edited to my answer and added a step by step solution.

Comment: @user127001  has complete answer,see him

Comment: you're welcome. btw: please do not forget to accept the answers to your question if you are contented with it. I've seen you haven't done this for all your previous questions.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do that? I have already accepted your answer with most sincere gratitude, that's why I thanked you, is there anything else to do?

Comment: Okay, got it, done, thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to  find inverse of function $f(x)=y$  ,try to replace places for $x$ and $y$ or use $f(y)=x$ and solve it to back to $y$ ,in your case  set

$x=(y-1)/(ln(y)$  ,now  interpret $y$  by $x$

now  we have following ine

$x*ln(y)=(y-1)$

or

$ln(y)/(y-1)=1/x$

now please take  on exponent form and also please note that $e^{ln(x)}=x$

Comment: Yes, this is where I'm stuck, interpreting y by x, I want to know how do you obtain the omega function or the product log function here? Could you please work this out for me? please.